# Is it possible to have the opacity as a function of the input variable in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, opacity

It is possible to make a `Plot3D` of a function $f(x,y)$, and to have the plot having its opacity $\alpha$ decrease as $x$ increases? For example say the plot has a range $x \in (0,10)$, and the opacity should be $\alpha = 1$ (fully non-transparent) for $x \in (0,8)$ and $\alpha = \frac{10-x}{2}$ for $x \in (8,10)$ (fully transparent at $x=10$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `ColorFunction`:

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# < 8, 1, (10 - #)/2], 
     ColorData[97, 2]] &)]
```

[image]

A couple of things to point out:

- this is setting `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` so that the formulas are in the form you specified them.
- you won't get the normal surface colors if your color function is just `Opacity`, so I added the default color to the color function.  One consequence it that you generally won't be able to do this with multiple functions in the same call to `Plot3D`.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! If I were to use a color scheme such as "BlueGreenYellow", how would the syntax change?

Comment: Assuming coloring by height, Instead of `ColorData[97, 2]` one way would be to change `ColorData["BlueGreenYellow", #3]` inside the color function and change `ColorFunctionScaling -> {False, False, True}`.  If you want the fade and color to use the same parameters (x/y/z) then you might need to do some manual rescaling one way or the other.

Comment: `Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# < 8, 1, (10 - #)/2], ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][Rescale[#, {0, 10}]]] &)]`

Comment: A hack-ish alternative is to use `Append[]` on the color object resulting from e.g. `ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"]`, which is effectively tacking on an extra alpha channel argument. Using Brett's example, `Plot3D[x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> (Append[ColorData[97, 2], If[# < 8, 1, (10 - #)/2]] &)]`